# Bootstrap grid alignment issue in col-xs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, grid

I'm building a layout with square size-ratio images nested inside Bootstrap columns.
This works good on desktop, but it fails on mobile when resizing the browser. 
**You can see what i mean between 753px-618px** http://www.bootply.com/yuxNss81CC

*This is caused by the columns not keeping the images width, while it is the normal behavior >768px*

I have done some testing and it does not seem a problem caused by my CSS.
As you can imagine this is a mess with something as easy as an :hover effect.
This is not the first time I encounter this problem and I'm getting frustrated.
Do you have any idea why it does behave this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it quite hard to understand what exactly you want, but some suggestions.

First of all don't touch Bootstrap's grid classes (e.g. the `.more-pad` and `.padding-fix-left` classes unless you absolutely need to. You'll likely break its behaviour.

In this case I have the idea you want to have a centered image inside the column that's responsive. Try adding the `.img-responsive` class to make it a responsive image. As it won't become larger than 300px surround it with a `<div>` that either has `max-width: 300px` and `margin: 0 auto` to center it in the column or make it `display: inline-block` and add the `text-center` class to the columns (I've opted for the latter in my example). Set the `<div>` to `position: relative` to allow the text to be positioned on top of the image.

See this example:

```css
.btn-image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: start;
}
.btn-image__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.btn-image:hover .btn-image__text {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <div class="btn-image">
        <div class="img-background">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300/888888" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-image__text">
          <p>Hello!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <div class="btn-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/666666" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="btn-image__text">
          <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <div class="btn-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/888888" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="btn-image__text">
          <p>Hello...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 text-center">
      <div class="btn-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300/666666" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="btn-image__text">
          <p>uhm..hello?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was as simple as adding 'display:inline-block' to the div surrounding the image. As for the classes _more-pad_ and _padding-fix_ ... it's a work in progress and i mean to clean it up later, but as you suggested, it is a little messy. I'm still learning and you were useful in helping me. Thank you again